# Javascript/jQuery HD toggle on flowplayer

Tags: javascript, jquery, flowplayer

Hi
I see someone made a HD toggle on flowplayer, could anyone advise the code of toggle between HD video and SD video?
Reference: http://www.shoutfilm.com/film/14-attrition-2009/

Comment: The easiest way is to use two video players and only have one shown and playing.

Comment: Good idea, but if I have 10 videos and I am playing the third video, how can I detect which SD video is and changing to the HD video?

Answer (score 0):

http://flowplayer.org/plugins/streaming/bwcheck.html

This plugin may be what you are after. It detects if there is a bandwidth bottleneck and changes to a lower quality stream. You will need to use a RTSP server for this so the video can seek to the appropriate point in time.

Comment: Thanks for the information, I am using RTSP(streaming server) , but I would like to let the user to switch between SD and HD.

Comment: It looks like you can attach a script to a button. http://flowplayer.org/demos/plugins/streaming/bwcheck-selection.html Sorry I can't help you more but nobody else has answered.

Comment: Yes, I should attach a script to a button, but I can't figure out how the script is. I see a example here http://www.shoutfilm.com/film/14-attrition-2009/, but I can't find the sources.

Comment: Did you figure out this yet? let us know i also need the answer, i try searching but i didn't have enough information.